# IllegalStateException: Already connected right after openConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I'm trying to setDoOutput in my HttpURLConnection but i keep getting this damn exception, and i dont know what to do because the code is basically a CTRL+C/V from around the web!!! check this it out:

```
url = new URL(Constants.Shared.API_URL+"registration");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);//BOOM!
```

Right after i execute `conn.setDoOutput` i get a free ticket to the catch block, and the exception is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected`!!!

The funny is that even [google documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (see Posting Content part) tells me to do as i am doing!!! What am i doing wrong here?!?

**Edit1: Stack Trace**
[java.net.URLConnection.checkNotConnected(URLConnection.java:464), java.net.URLConnection.setDoOutput(URLConnection.java:878), br.com.aec.acs.service.IntegracaoService.RegisterCloudUser(IntegracaoService.java:118), br.com.aec.acs.service.IdentityService.RegisterNewACS(IdentityService.java:49), br.com.aec.acs.RegistrationActivity.ButtonOkClicked(RegistrationActivity.java:40), br.com.aec.acs.RegistrationActivity_$1.onClick(RegistrationActivity_.java:52), android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240), android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721), android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730), android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92), android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137), android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103), java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method), java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525), com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737), com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553), dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)]

Comment: can you post all the stack trace

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin check edit1